# clock model not displayed in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was going through gazebo tutorial at : http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials
, when I launch empty world I didn't see clock model, only gplane and point_white is being shown.
I am not able to control the speed of simulation.

Launch file empty_world.launch has

line.

Am I missing something.
What is needed to be done to bring the clock model and control the speed of simulation.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29675/clock-model-not-displayed-in-gazebo/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-03-14**:
Are you referring to the "use_sim_time" parameter? What clock model are you referring to?

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-03-14**:
As in the tutorial : http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo In the figure that is displayed (on the page), I can see on top left, under model:-
clock,
gplane, &
point_white
but whne I run  'roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch'  I only see
gplane
point_white
& no clock

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-03-29**:
hi hsu,
by cont speed of sim' I mean, for eg,

1. I launched an empty gazebo world.
2. Span an empty cup
3. Applied a body wrench (as in http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API pt 9)
   Now, can I control the sim clock so that I see rotation faster or slower?

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-03-29**:
hi hsu,
by cont speed of sim' I mean, for eg,

1. I launched an empty gazebo world.
2. Span an empty cup
3. Applied a body wrench (as in http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API pt 9)
   Now, can I control the sim clock so that I see rotation faster or slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are talking about the ["clock model" in diamondback](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.0/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world),
as of electric, the "clock model" has been removed from the [world file](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.2/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world).  The [gazebo binary built from gazeboros.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo/src/gazeboros.cpp) contains a publisher for `/clock` and various services such as the model factory for spawning models.  In fuerte, the model is slightly shifted as all ros related topics/services are now available there through [system plugins](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp), invoked by loading them with the `-p` option when [starting up gazebo](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo/scripts/gazebo).

In terms of "controlling the speed of simulation", can you explain in more detail what you mean by it?  Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1